# Los estilos CSS no se aplican a mi código HTML en Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

El código tal cual está aquí funciona en [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer), pero en [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) no aplica los estilos.

Ya intenté limpiar el *cache* del navegador y no funciona.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <style>
    table {
      border: 5 solid #ff0033
    }
    td {
      border: 5 solid
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>hola
        <td>Hola
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: amigo tienes etiquetas html sin cerrar, como el tr y los td

Comment: Está en inglés. Este sitio es en español.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Importante destacar que este site sólo es en español. Por tanto es importante mantenernos todos dentro de las normas y lineamientos que lo regulan.

Comment: jaja, olvidé lo del idioma. Ya he cerrado todos los tags y no funciona per solamente en chrome. Como dije, Internet explorer sí lo hace así como lo escribí.

Comment: por que no la traduces así la reabrimos, excepto por el ingles, es una pregunta valida.

Comment: La mayoría de los navegadores de esta década lo entenderá y cerrará automáticamente los tags abiertos, en cuanto al idioma, @rnrneverdies te aviso que pueden dar click en editar, traducirlo y llevarse puntos de experiencia por ello ;)

Comment: si estas seguro que tienes las rutas correctas, borra la cache del navegador y vuelve a revisar tu pagina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes definir las unidades a usar, por ejemplo para pixeles puedes usar el sufijo `px`:

```css
table {
  border: 5px solid #ff0033;
}
td {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hola
      <td>Hola
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Además de contestar sin criticar mi error con el idioma, me acabas de solucionar la vida. =)

Comment: Y pensar que las unidades eran lo único que a chrome le faltaba. No entiendo cómo explorer sí lo abrió sin las unidades o_O

Comment: Si tranquilo, pero para que la respuesta le sirva a otras personas te agradecería que traducieras la pregunta. Así apoyas al crecimiento de la comunidad en español.

Comment: Cómo edito mi pregunta? :P

Comment: Olvídalo, ya lo hice. Gracias! =)

Comment: Si ya me di cuenta ;) Bienvenido

Comment: De hecho.. no te preocupes por traducir, hay mucha gente que a veces se molesta, pero al verdad es que a los que podemos editar nos regalas muchos puntos, y generalmente la traducción es un poco mejor pues llevamos hablando el caste4llano de toda la vida. Obviamente explorer tiende a asumir siempre que las unidades son píxels por ser mucho más viejo que los demás navegadores. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tuve un problema parecido y ya lo resolví, tenía las rutas así:

- Proyecto/HTML/index.html
- Proyecto/css/style.css

  Para que enlacen debe ser:
- Proyecto/index.html
- Proyecto/css/style.css

El archivo .html, debe estar en el directorio raíz.

Saludos!!

Comment: Que tal Diana... Bienvenida... primero, esta bien que respondas a tus preguntas, pero seria bueno que la hagas en base a lo que tu pregunta apunta (ademas de mostrar siempre el código para que otras personas que tal vez tengan los mismos problema sepan como resolverlo)...